# Is my PI broken or the LCD screen?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, lcd

So I have an LCD screen which plugs into the pi. The pi works fine, but when I do the whole LCD-show in the terminal and it restarts it stops at either “starting login service” or “starting message bus”, and there is no output to the screen, I’ve reinstalled raspian twice now and I’ve had the same problem both times. I would think it’s the pi, but before I change to LCD it works fine. Any ideas?

The screen is [Elegoo 3.5 inch display](https://www.elegoo.com/product/elegoo-3-5-inch-480x320-tft-touch-screen-monitor/)

Comment: which lcd screen?

Comment: ELEGOO 3.5 Inch

Comment: Please add additional information to the question using the [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/111038/edit) link below it.

Comment: First step I would take is to remove the screen, start with a fresh image of Raspbian Lite WITH NO CHANGES and see if that boots using a keyboard and HDMI monitor.  Could you please add what Pi you have and what power supply you are using.

Comment: `it stops at` Where do you see output stops? I that on the LCD, an external (HDMI) monitor or a remote session (SSH). It's normal that HDMI output stops when you run LCD-show. It should appear on the LCD after that.

Comment: The output stops on the hdmi after I have switched it to the LCD, I have tried taking off the LCD and starting with a fresh raspian and it works fine, out when I switch it over to “LCD-show” it stops